# Ember i18n - interpolation to call translations dynamically

Tags: ember-i18n

Is it possible to call a translation dynamically using interpolation in a template? I'd like to get something like that from this version:

```
<label for="{{media.type}}">{{t 'social.labels.twitter'}}</label>
```

to the below one using interpolation:

```
<label for="{{media.type}}">{{t 'social.labels.'{{model.some_media_name}}}}</label>
```

As you see, I' like to call a label translation for a specified social media based on its model value. The above snippet does not work.
Any ideas ? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I fond the answer at one of [ember-i18n issues](https://github.com/jamesarosen/ember-i18n/issues/471), you should just use `concat` function as follows:

```
<label for="{{media.type}}">{{t (concat "social.labels." media.type)}}</label>
```

What will look for a translation key `social.labels.twiiter` in case of `media.type` equals to `twitter`.